# SSH version update to 7.4 in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, security, openssh

I am using qualys for security scan on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It is reporting these vulnerabilities [CVE-2016-8858](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-8858),[CVE-2016-10009](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-10009),[CVE-2016-10010](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-10010),[CVE-2016-10011](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-10011),[CVE-2016-10012](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-10012) which require openssh 7.4 .

This is a serious thing for us which is stopping us from being compliant. I want to know if there is an official way to update OpenSSH version to 7.4 in ubuntu 14 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453976/upgrade-openssh-7-2p-in-ubuntu-14-04), or by when should I expect ubuntu to release security patches for these vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Installing OpenSSH 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
wget "https://fastly.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz"
tar xfz openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.4p1
./configure
make
sudo make install && sudo service ssh restart && ssh -V
```

Comment: Take care: `./configure`  uses directories under `/usr/local` which isn't the "standard" location for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to upgrade OpenSSH to 7.4 in Ubuntu 14.04, and since thuse bugs from 2016 are not yet fixed, they are probably considered very low priority and expecting them to be fixed in any timeframe is probably unreasonable.

In any case, if security is so important to you, you should hire someone who knows what they are doing; they can build you a 7.4 package very easily.